# What are the package and subpackage comment for?

Tags: plugins, themes, comments

This is included in themes and plugins.

```
/*
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
```

What are they for? I've read that they are standard and so on, but what is the practical use for it?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) tags - used to generate meaningful (and automated) code documentation